# Get the first column of date linux

Tags: linux, date

When I run `date` on my linux I get `Sat Oct 31 11:53:22 BRST 2015`. I want to get only `Sat`. How do I do that? So far I think I should use the code below but it does not work:

```
date | printf $1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`date` can output what you want without help of other commands:

```
$ date +%a
Sat
```

For more details: `man 1 date`

Comment: great answer :) The other answer was also perfect but yours is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`date | cut -d' ' -f1`

`man 1 cut` will give you explanation.

Comment: great answer man I didnt know "cut" but the answer of yeti is a little easier. Anyway thank you so much!